# How to receive arguments via shell pipe in python?

Tags: python, linux, shell, pipe

I would like to do something like this:

```
find -name "foo*" | python main.py
```

and access all the files that were found by the find program. How do I access that in Python?

Comment: What about command which ran for a long time, e.g `top`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line
```

Answer (score 4):

Use sys.stdin.read() or raw_input()

A pipeline just changes the stdin file descriptor to point to the pipeline that the command on the left is writing to.

Answer (score 4):

I Like using $(...) for command-line arguments that are dependent on some other program. I think this would work for your program `python main.py $(find -name "foo*")`. Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902928/python-argparse-unix-piping-to-arguments)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do:

```
import sys
print sys.stdin.readlines() #or what you want
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html) may be what you want.