# Python argparse & Unix piping to arguments

Tags: python, unix, pipe, command-line-arguments, argparse

Suppose I want the output from `rsgen.py` to be used as the `references` argument of my `simulate.py` script. How can I do it?

In `simulate.py`

```
parser.add_argument("references", metavar="RS", type=int, nargs="+", help="Reference string to use")
```

I tried

```
# ./simulate.py references < rs.txt 
usage: simulate.py [-h] [--numFrames F] [--numPages P] RS [RS ...]
simulate.py: error: argument RS: invalid int value: 'references'

# ./simulate.py < rs.txt 
usage: simulate.py [-h] [--numFrames F] [--numPages P] RS [RS ...]
simulate.py: error: too few arguments
```

I believe my piping syntax is wrong, how can I fix it?

Idealy, I want to directly pipe the output from `rsgen.py` into the `references` argument of `simulate.py`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean you want to use the output of rsgen.py as command line parameters to simulate.py, use backquotes which run the contained command and place the output into the command line

```
    ./simulate.py `./rsgen.py`
```

Comment: another syntax is $ ./simulate.py $(rsgen.py) by imho $ ./rsgen.py | ./simulate.py is better.

Comment: This is the simplest and most widely supported shell syntax for turning program output into a commandline argument. You don't need to worry about nesting or anything else with your use case. But don't use this if the output of rsgen is really enormous: In that case, use a pipe and have simulate.py read from stdin.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to give the output of `rsgen.py` as an argument, your best solution is to use [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html). The syntax varies according to the shell you're using, but the following will work on most modern shells:

```
./simulate.py references $(./rsgen.py)
```

*Side note, Brian Swift's answer uses backticks for command substitution. The syntax is valid on most shells as well, but has the disadvantage of not nesting really well.*

On the other hand, if you want to pipe the output of a script into another, you should read from `sys.stdin`

Example:

**a.py**

```
print "hello world"
```

**b.py**

```
import sys

for i in sys.stdin:
    print "b", i
```

**result**:

```
$ ./a.py | ./b.py
b hello world
```

Comment: It would look like this in python 3
```import sys [NEWLINE]
for line in sys.stdin: [NEWLINE] 
    print("###", line)```